Import JSON File in Neo4J with apoc.periodic.iterate
I need to import a big JSON file in Neo4J.
Because it should be quite fast I wanted to use apoc.periodic.iterate
My Approach is the following
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  "CALL apoc.load.json('sampled.json') YIELD value RETURN value",
  "UNWIND value.authors AS author
   WITH author
   WHERE author.id <> '' AND author.name <> '' 
   MERGE (a:Author {id:author.id})
   ON CREATE SET a.name = author.name",
  {batchSize:1000, parallel:false}
)

My problem is that the query doesnt terminate.
I can't figure out what the problem is and how to fix it.

what is that pipe (|) doing in the script?

this was a mistake by me. I edited the question

You are using apoc.periodic.iterate improperly. The first query passed to the method should UNWIND value.authors so that the second query can actually receive batches of authors (instead of the entire JSON object all at once).
And you should also consider creating an appropriate index to make the MERGE even faster.
For example (you can adjust the batchSize as appropriate, and even use true for parallel if the JSON file does not contain duplicate authors):
CREATE INDEX author_id IF NOT EXISTS FOR (a:Author) ON (a.id)

CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  "CALL apoc.load.json('sampled.json') YIELD value
   UNWIND value.authors AS author
   WITH author WHERE author.id <> '' AND author.name <> ''
   RETURN author",
  "MERGE (a:Author {id:author.id})
   ON CREATE SET a.name = author.name",
  {batchSize: 10000, parallel: false}
)

